# Does my laptop/motherboard support SATA 3?

Tags: windows, laptop, ssd, sata

My laptop is an `HP Pavilion G6-2209sl`.
I want to buy an SSD, so I'd like to know if my laptop is SATA III (6 GB/s) compatible.
Thanks to CPU-Z software, I discovered that the motherboard model is `1840 56.2C`, if it can be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That laptop originally came with Sata II hard drives.

Since there is no technical info on that motherboard one could safely assume it  supports Sata II and is forward compatible with Sata III but will run at Sata II speeds.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So is it convenient to buy an SSD? Will I have any advantages?

Comment: SSD will perform much faster than a spinning hard drive, buy one made by Samsung, I find these the best bang for the buck.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.
PS: Where did you find the information in the picture above?

Comment: On you support page for that model in a Maintenance and Service guide document....https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pavilion-g6-2200-notebook-pc-series/5296082/model/5322139/manuals

Comment: Looking at your picture, it seems that it is the basic SATA (300 Mbps), so it is neither sata 2 (3.0 Gbps) nor sata 3 (6.0 Gbps)...I don't think it's correct.
So I ran hwinfo software (https://www.hwinfo.com/), and its output tells me that my SATA Host Controller supports an interface speed of  6.0 Gbps, so it would be SATA III.
I hope it's right.

Comment: That image shows the transfer rate for the hard drive, not the sata host controller, I made a wild guess based on the era of that model since there are no published specs for that motherboard, lmk if the hwinfo is correct.